# Applescript for Apple Numbers, Move data around from a single column

Tags: applescript, apple-numbers

I am trying to use Applescript to help automate cleanup of a spreadysheet

I have a spreadsheet with all the data in a single column, basically a monetary amound and a date. I am trying to separate them out of the single column into columns A and B

Basically Every 3 rows is a dollar amount, and the following every three rows is date. The 3rd set is junk data that can be deleted with find and replace to "" (black) which I have working. The raw data looks like this.

```
$500.00 
January 1 2023
-JUNKdata-
$400.00 
January 2 2023
-JUNKdata-
$600.00 
January 3 2023
-JUNKdata-
```

I am trying to get it to translate to (with | being cell separator between A and B)

```
$500.00 | January 1 2023
$400.00 | January 2 2023
$600.00 | January 3 2023
```

and so on.

Is there an easy way to do this with Applescript? I was able to get find and replace working to get ride of the junk data that is always the same data but beyond that I'm a bit lost.

I am not a programmer so I am completely lost and trying to look at tutorials I can't seem to find commands I am looking for. I have tried to use select, copy, paste with ranges and manually typing out the rows such as A1, A4, A7) but I keep getting errors. I'm trying to be hacky with it but I can't even get that far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have "Automatic" format for cells of columns "A" and "B", you can do something like this:

```
tell application "Numbers" to tell document 1 to tell sheet 1 to tell table 1
    
    set theData to value of cells of column "A" -- remeber the data as AppleScript list
    clear column "A" -- clear contents of column "A"
    -- set format of column "B" to text -- force text format for column "B" 
    
    set j to 0 -- set additional counter
    repeat with i from 1 to (count theData) - 2 by 3
        set j to j + 1
        set value of cell j of column "A" to item i of theData
        set value of cell j of column "B" to item (i + 1) of theData
    end repeat
    
end tell
```

NOTE: If you need "Text" format instead, then uncomment -- set format of column "B" to text code line.

If you have columns "A" and "B" initially in text format, then you can get a big gain in script speed from this. You can filter all empty (missing value) elements from theData at once, getting only **text type** elements of theData. Using **ignoring application responses**, you can also improve the speed several times.

```
tell application "Numbers" to tell document 1 to tell sheet 1 to tell table 1
    set theData to text of (get value of cells of column "A") -- remeber the data as AppleScript list
    
    ignoring application responses -- speed up
        clear column "A" -- clear contents of column "A"
        set j to 0 -- set additional counter
        repeat with i from 1 to (count theData) - 2 by 3
            set j to j + 1
            set value of cell j of column "A" to item i of theData
            set value of cell j of column "B" to item (i + 1) of theData
        end repeat
    end ignoring
    
end tell
```

Comment: This is PERFECT It works just as intended. Thank you so much!